# How can I execute data from SQlite to UiTableView?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview

I created database that includes one entity: People. The entity has two Attributes: Surname and Age.

I have `UIViewController` with `@IBOutlet var tblPeople: UITableView!`.

How can execute all data from data base and show on the `UITableView`?

(I have one more controller where I can create new data about people and save to data base).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make your UIViewController subclass as the table view data source and delegate. Then you will need to implement appropriate data source methods, so that the table view can load the contents using appropriate UITableViewCell subclasses to render the rows. 
Do refer some good tutorials on Table View programming such as this one-
http://makeapppie.com/2015/02/17/swift-swift-tutorials-introducing-table-views/